# The text of my label "scroll" should be scrolling like marque effects of HTML

Tags: java, swing

The text of my jlabel2 `"scroll"` should be scrolling like marquee effects of HTML in java swing. Some tags of html is working but marquee tag is not workes.

[image]

Comment: http://java-sl.com/marquee.html

Comment: *"Some tags of html is working but marquee tag is not work.."*  'Marquee' is not part of the HTML standard.  Swing HTML will never implement non-standard HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Marquee Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/04/24/marquee-panel/) which supports horizontal scrolling.